# reading gzipped csv file in python 3

Tags: python, csv, gzip

I'm having problems reading from a gzipped csv file with the `gzip` and `csv` libs. Here's what I got:

```
import gzip
import csv
import json

f = gzip.open(filename)
csvobj = csv.reader(f,delimiter = ',',quotechar="'")
for line in csvobj:
            ts = line[0]
            data_json = json.loads(line[1])
```

but this throws an exception:

```
 File "C:\Users\yaronol\workspace\raw_data_from_s3\s3_data_parser.py", line 64, in download_from_S3
    self.parse_dump_file(filename)
  File "C:\Users\yaronol\workspace\raw_data_from_s3\s3_data_parser.py", line 30, in parse_dump_file
    for line in csvobj:
_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)
```

gunzipping the file and opening that with csv works fine. I've also tried decoding the file text to convert from bytes to str...

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Default mode for `gzip.open` is `rb`, if you wish to work with strs, you have to specify it extra:

```
f = gzip.open(filename, mode="rt")
```

OT: it is a good practice to write I/O operations in a with block:

```
with gzip.open(filename, mode="rt") as f:
```

Comment: you should also [add `newline=''` to gzip.open()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/csv.html#csv.reader)

Answer (score 4):

You are opening the file in binary mode ([which is the default for `gzip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html#gzip.open)).

Try instead:

```
import gzip
import csv
f = gzip.open(filename, mode='rt')
csvobj = csv.reader(f,delimiter = ',',quotechar="'")
```

Answer (score 1):

too late, you can use datatable package in python

```
import datatable as dt
df = dt.fread(filename)
df.head()
```